# How to use publish_action permission of facebook api?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to post base64 encoded images in facebook. Below is my code

```
 function postImageToFacebook(authToken, filename, mimeType, imageData, message) {
        // this is the multipart/form-data boundary we'll use
        var boundary = '----ThisIsTheBoundary1234567890';
        // let's encode our image file, which is contained in the var
        var formData = '--' + boundary + '\r\n'
        formData += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="source"; filename="' + filename + '"\r\n';
        formData += 'Content-Type: ' + mimeType + '\r\n\r\n';
        for (var i = 0; i < imageData.length; ++i) {
          formData += String.fromCharCode(imageData[i] & 0xff);
        }
        formData += '\r\n';
        formData += '--' + boundary + '\r\n';
        formData += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="message"\r\n\r\n';
        formData += message + '\r\n'
        formData += '--' + boundary + '--\r\n';

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token=' + authToken, true);
        xhr.onload = xhr.onerror = function () {
          console.log(xhr.responseText);
        };
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
        if(!xhr.sendAsBinary){
          xhr.sendAsBinary = function(datastr) {
            function byteValue(x) {
              return x.charCodeAt(0) & 0xff;
            }
            var ords = Array.prototype.map.call(datastr, byteValue);
            var ui8a = new Uint8Array(ords);
            this.send(ui8a.buffer);
          }
        }
        xhr.sendAsBinary(formData);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            alert('Your image has been successfully shared');
          }
        }
      };

      var data = yourDesigner.getProductDataURL();
      var encodedPng = data.substring(data.indexOf(',') + 1, data.length);
      var decodedPng = Base64Binary.decode(encodedPng);
      // var decodedPng = dataURItoBlob(test,"png");
      FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        var request = {};
        if (response.status === "connected") {
          request = postImageToFacebook(response.authResponse.accessToken, "test", "image/png", decodedPng, "www.captivations.com.au");
        } else if (response.status === "not_authorized") {
          FB.login(function (response) {
            request = postImageToFacebook(response.authResponse.accessToken, "test", "image/png", decodedPng, "www.captivations.com.au");
          }, {scope: "publish_actions"});
        } else {
          FB.login(function (response) {
            request = postImageToFacebook(response.authResponse.accessToken, "test", "image/png", decodedPng, "www.captivations.com.au");
          }, {scope: "publish_actions"});
        }
      });
```

I can post images when i logged into my facebook account . But when i tried to post the images from other accounts i got following error

> "error": {
>         "message": "(#200) Requires extended permission: publish_actions",
>         "type": "OAuthException",
>         "code": 200,
>         "fbtrace_id": "EAcb5VG/eFS"
>      }

I think its permission issue of the facbook api. Can you help me on managing "publish action" permission of facebook?

Answer (score 0):

From https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions:

> The "publish_actions" provides access to publish Posts, Open Graph actions, achievements, scores and other activity on behalf of a person using your app.
>
> Your app does not need to request the publish_actions permission in order to use the Feed Dialog, the Requests Dialog or the Send Dialog.

If you use the "publish_actions" permission in another way you have to requests Facebook to review how your app uses the "publish_actions" permission.

Comment: i am not using  Feed Dialog, the Requests Dialog or the Send Dialog. I am just sending post request to facebook. Its working when my account is logged but sending error when sending request from others account

Comment: @bittu: Remove the app from your settings, and then log in again. And this time, _pay attention_ to the message the login dialog shows you.